# How can i send a SMS, using an activity class, inside an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sms

I need to send a SMS from my AsyncTask. So i create this activity called SMS.
Im my AsyncTask i got this constructor:

```
public AsyncTask(Context pContext, TextView pTxtWorkProgress, TextView pTxtMsg, ProgressBar pProgressbar_line, SMS pSmsActivity){
        context = pContext;
        txtMsg = pTxtMsg;
        txtWorkProgress = pTxtWorkProgress;
        progressbar_line = pProgressbar_line;
        smsActivity = pSmsActivity;
    }
```

Then, in my doInBackground(), i got the code:

```
if(smsActivity != null)
 smsActivity.sendSMS("9999", "4444");
else
 hasErrorSms = true;
```

In my smsActivity, i got the method sendSMS():

```
public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message){        
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);

    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Util.mSMS_SENT_STATUS = Util.mSMS_SENT_RESULT_OK;
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Util.mSMS_SENT_STATUS = Util.mSMS_SENT_RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE;                        
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Util.mSMS_SENT_STATUS = Util.mSMS_SENT_RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE;                        
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Util.mSMS_SENT_STATUS = Util.mSMS_SENT_RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU;                        
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Util.mSMS_SENT_STATUS = Util.mSMS_SENT_RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF;                        
                    break;
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
    }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));        

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);        
}
```

But its not working, i got a NullPointerException when i trie to get a Intent inside SMS class.

This is how i call the AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask(this, txtWorkProgress, txtMsg, progressbar_line, new SMS()).execute(larr_what_have_to_upate_in_device.toString(), lCD_DEVIC);
```

I know that the new SMS() its not working, someone could tell me how can I do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Which line is the NPE on? Aka show us logcat.

Comment: @David Olsson Hi, NPE in line: `PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);` I think i'm not doing right when i call the AsyncTask: `new AsyncTask(this, txtWorkProgress, txtMsg, progressbar_line, new SMS()).execute(larr_what_have_to_upate_in_device.toString(), lCD_DEVIC);`

Answer (score 1):

You reported that the crash is occuring in line:

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
```

I have successfully setup these intents like this in the past:

```
public static final String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
public static final String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

final String name = "Some-Name";
final PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    (new Intent(SENT)).putExtra("name", name),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
final PendingIntent delivedPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
    (new Intent(DELIVERED)).putExtra("name", name),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Therefore, try adding the extra data `name` and the `PendingIntent.FLAG` value as above.

Comment: Hey, the crash is occuring in line: `PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);` I think i'm doing the wrong way passing new SMS() when i call the AsyncTask: `new AsyncTask(this, txtWorkProgress, txtMsg, progressbar_line, new SMS()).execute(larr_what_have_to_upate_in_device.toString(), lCD_DEVIC);`.

Comment: Someone with a bit more experience could give me a little help please? Thanks.